# Video effect - slowmotion to fastmotion?

Tags: editing, slowmotion

How do you edit a video using Premiere Pro CC 2017 so that it goes from slow motion to normal speed or fast motion, like in [this video](https://www.facebook.com/tomorrowland/videos/10154017139189177/). Some parts are in slow motion and then it suddenly speeds up?

Answer (score 1):

The term your looking for is called a **speed ramp**. There are lots of tutorials if you search for that.

Here are basic instructions for one way of doing that.

- Right click on the clip in your timeline
- Click '*Show Clip Keyframes*' then '*Time Remapping*' then '*Speed*'
- You can then add Keyframes and drag the line on your clip to alter the speed